# copyValuesToRange the same line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a little script that copies all line values obtained by a formula, to that same line without the formula.

I'm trying to use `copyValuesToRange` on the same line. (I would get the values calculated on a certain line and I would overlap them with those same values, fomula free).

A little contextualization... I'm doing a kind of record/pre-vision of values for a game. On the same sheet I have past records, the today's record and values that are still to happen.

To obtain those values the sheet performs a few calculations per line but i want it only to calculate values that havent happened yet. So, each day, the sheet should perform an operation that clears the formulas from the previous day. For this i tried doing the following:

```
function example(oRow){

    var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetRecord = app.getSheetByName("Record");

    sheetRecord.getRange(oRow-1,1,1,18)
      .copyValuesToRange(sheetRecord,1,18,oRow-1,oRow-1);
}
```

oRow is the row number of the line that i want this operation to occur.

This is either doing nothing or still copying the formulas to the same cells.

I'm sure it's some stupid litte thing that I'm missing, but i can't put my finger on it.

How can i fix this? Or is there a simpler way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me. For example, when I run the function with cell containing the formula "=5+3", it is overwritten with "8" (not a formula). Can you provide an example case that demonstrates your error?

Comment: Yes, i tried using it with a single cell for that line and with an example similar to yours and it works perfectly. 
Here's a copy of the spreadsheet I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AibhIph6tDbtdDBGc21NQ3QxeGJ1Y19JbzJPQ2JIdlE#gid=0

Comment: So your issue is with multiple cells?

Comment: I think i solved my problem and like i said, it was a stupid litle mistake.
The order of the positional arguments of getRange and copyValuesToRange are different. So, for the problem i showed it would have to be: sheetRecord.getRange(oRow-1,1,1,18).copyValuesToRange(sheetRecord,1,18,oRow-1,oRow-1);
Thanks for your help Kalyan, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of the functions getRange() and copyValuesToRange() i showed above on the question are missplaced.

The functionas are:

```
getRange(row, column, optNumRows, optNumColumns)


copyValuesToRange(sheet, startColumn, endColumn, startRow, endRow)
```

So if I want to copy the values of the, for example, row 9 from column 1 to 15 ("A9:P9") to that same row, i would have to do the following:

```
sheetRecord.getRange(oRow-1,1,1,18).copyValuesToRange(sheetRecord,1,18,oRow-1,oRow-1);
```

instead of what's above on the question.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I wanted to copy the cells and paste back as values, in `row`, columns 4 and 5, so used `  var range = dataSs.getRange(row, 4, 1, 2);  range.copyValuesToRange(dataSs, 4, 5, row, row);